# How to print neatly table from database

Tags: wpf

I try to print a table from a database but it prints in an irregular way

It looks like this:

```
text text text text

text text   text  text

text text     text...............
```

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader thereader = com.ExecuteReader();

while (thereader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < thereader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        DataApear.Text += thereader.GetValue(i)+"                   ";
    }
    DataApear.Text += "\n";
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: You need all the entries in a column to be the same length. You could work out tye maximum and use padright to that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding .   Not sure why you want to do this but saving as xml or csv might be something to consider. Save as a csv and later double click the file. It'll (usually) open it up in excel. Excel is pretty good at lining stuff up into columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Alignment Component in String.Format like so (from [String.Format docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#controlling-alignment)) :

```
int[] years = { 2013, 2014, 2015 };
int[] population = { 1025632, 1105967, 1148203 };
String s = String.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10}\n\n", "Year", "Population");
for(int index = 0; index < years.Length; index++)
   s += String.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10:N0}\n",
                  years[index], population[index]);
Console.WriteLine($"\n{s}");
// Result:
//    Year       Population
//
//    2013       1,025,632
//    2014       1,105,967
//    2015       1,148,203
```